# Spring Cache AspectJ Mode not working since J17 upgrade

Tags: aspectj

I am using AspectJ mode for caching. However, as soon as I enable it, the @Cacheable annotation which is declared over public methods on one of my dependencies do not work. Have enabled Load Time Weaving. This started happening since we upgraded to J17.

Spring Boot: 2.7.8
AspectjWeaver: 1.9.7
Java: 17

Any head-starts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the [AspectJ 1.9.7 release notes](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/eclipse/org.aspectj/blob/master/docs/dist/doc/README-197.html)?

> #### Using LTW on Java 16+
>
> Please note that if you want to use load-time weaving on Java 16+, the weaving agent collides with [JEP 396 (Strongly Encapsulate JDK Internals by Default)](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/396). Therefore, you need to set the JVM parameter `--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED` in order to enable aspect weaving. This is due to the fact that the weaver uses internal APIs for which we have not found an adequate replacement yet when defining classes in different classloaders.

The same paragraph is also contained in all more recent release notes up to 1.9.19.

Comment: Hi, Thanks fr updating the same. I have already added the given JVM param.

Comment: Well, is it helping then? If so, please accept and upvote the answer. Just click the grey checkmark, turning it green, and the arrow up.

Comment: Oh it didn't help - I already have that as a JVM param in my project.

Comment: Then please learn [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you. Make your problem reproducible, don't just say "it is not working". Nobody can debug that.

Comment: Its the dependencies -Cacheable that doesn't work while my projects -Cacheble works.